# Cmidrule misplaced \noalign

Tags: tables, beamer, rules, alignment, booktabs

I am using cmidrule as I have used it before, but it's giving me strange errors. Below the MWE reproduces them. What is going on?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
    \begin{table}[tbh!]
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
            \toprule
                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(1)} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{(2)} \\
                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OUTCOME}} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OUTCOME}} \\
                        & \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \\
                        & I & II & III && I & II & III \\
           \midrule
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are missing the \\ to end the line.

Comment: Thanks, but does not solve the issue. Updated the MWE.

Comment: You also need to get rid of the superfluous `&` particle before `\cmidrule{2-4}`. And, while you're at it, do also get rid of double-backslash immediately after `\cmidrule{6-8}`; it's not a syntax error, but it's a typographical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
& \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \\
```

contains a syntax error (`&`) and a typographical error (`\\`).

There also seems to be no need for 8 columns when 6 will do just fine. For visual balance, I'd also omit the **bold-facing** of some of the header cells. Since we're dealing with a `beamer` document, there's no point in using a `table` float to encase the tabular material. To finish things off, here's an excerpt from section 2 of the user guide of the `booktabs` package (emphasis added by me):

[image]

Thus, use either `\midrule` or `\bottomrule`, *but not both*.

---

Here's how I would be tempted to reconfigure your table -- note the absence of whitespace padding on the left- and right-hand sides.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{MWE}
    % don't use figure and table floats in beamer docs
    %%\begin{table} 
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{(1)}     & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{(2)}     \\
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{OUTCOME} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{OUTCOME} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6} 
    I & II & III & I & II & III \\
    \midrule
    aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & ggg \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    %%\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow a lot of useful advice in here. I did not get the thing about the double rules. I thought this applied to not doing "\hline\hline". What do you mean? Deleting the \midrule?

Comment: And funny, I am also an economist.. our best journal love the double rules ;)

Comment: Welcome, fellow economist! :-) About the double-rule thing: My layout preference is to keep things as simple and uncluttered as possible. A single horizontal rule provides all the visual separation you'll ever need -- hence, no need to provide two horizontal rules. I'd use `\bottomrule` unless there's an excellent reason for using `\midrule`. (I can't think of one for the table at hand...)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code (with the rules after the `\\`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{MWE}
        \begin{table}[tbh!]
            \centering
            \footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
                \toprule
                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(1)} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{(2)} \\
                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OUTCOME}} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OUTCOME}} \\\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8}
                &  \\
                & I & II & III && I & II & III \\
                \midrule
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]